# maven doesn't recognize tests dependencies in additional test-source directories

Tags: maven-3, netbeans-7

I'm trying to separate unit tests and integration tests in the same project. I used the build-helper-maven-plugin to configure my additional sources folders ( for integration tests) as below:

```
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
      <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${integrationSourceDirectory}</source>
                            </sources>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${integrationResourceDirectory}</directory>
                                    <targetPath>${integrationOutputDirectory}</targetPath>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
....
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

When I open the project in netbeans 7.3.1. the additional source folder is recognized as "generated sources" and my test libraries are not included in the classpath of the classes indluded in this tests folder (ex. arquillian ).

How can I fix that in netbeans ?

Thanks in advance for your help